# Integrate instant messaging or chat system with my site developed in CakePHP

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.0, chat, message, cakephp-2.x

After searching on the net and with others I still have not found a solution to integrate instant messaging system with my site developed in CakePHP.
I found plugins but they are all for version 1.3. and my version of cakephp is 2.8.
Let me explain, I will wish to develop (or use an existing plugin ) an instant messaging system while having the ability to change the user status (online, offline, away, ...).

The user can view the old discussions and his lateral space will be positioned on the right for example listing all the people connected etc.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Cordially.

Comment: You can make use of quickblox API!

Comment: how  ? i'm a bigenner

Comment: https://developers.livechatinc.com/rest-api/#!introduction this also looks much promising though!

Comment: can i use a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

i thinks this solution you cannot found it because she need a special developpement .

Comment: can i develop chat with ajax then integrate it in cakephp ?

Comment: Yes we can develpp that ?

Comment: i think we can and we can use  NodeJS et Socket.IO https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/nodejs/socketio-tchat-366

Comment: its great but ou can use socket  without nodejs :                                                https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket/comment-page-1

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp is not prefect for real time operation. You can use nodeJS socket IO http://socket.io/get-started/chat/